# Multiple regex match and assignment in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, stringr

I am trying to match a regex which outputs several values and assign it in-place to several new variables inside a data.table

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

fruit_regex <- "(\\d+): apples=(.*), oranges=(.*)"

DT <- data.table(V1=c("1: apples=0.1, oranges=0.01",
            "2: apples=0.2, oranges=0.02",
            "3: apples=0.3, oranges=0.03",
            "4: apples=0.4, oranges=0.04",
            "5: apples=0.5, oranges=0.05"))

DT[, c("txt","id","apples", "oranges"):= as.list(str_match_all(V1, fruit_regex))]
```

This, of course, fails and I am getting

```
>Warning messages:
>1: In `[.data.table`(DT, , `:=`(c("txt", "id", "apples", "oranges"),  :
>  Supplied 4 columns to be assigned a list (length 5) of values (1 unused)
```

`str_match_all()` says to be vectorized over patterns and strings, but for some reason I can not get it to work.

There's another known issue with my regex which returns a redundant full match and can be cured with lookaround assertions.

Desired result(looking away from redundant `V1` and `txt` fields):

```
id apples oranges
1      0.1   0.01
2      0.2   0.02
3      0.3   0.03
4      0.4   0.04
5      0.5   0.05
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to transform your results into something that R can insert into the dataframe, such as another data frame.
For example, solved using the "plyr" package

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)
library(plyr)
fruit_regex <- "(\\d+): apples=(.*), oranges=(.*)"

DT <- data.table(V1=c("1: apples=0.1, oranges=0.01",
        "2: apples=0.2, oranges=0.02",
        "3: apples=0.3, oranges=0.03",
        "4: apples=0.4, oranges=0.04",
        "5: apples=0.5, oranges=0.05"))

DT[, c("txt","id","apples", "oranges"):= ldply(str_match_all(V1, fruit_regex))]
```

Comment: Shahar, thank you very much for bringing up the `ldply`. I also realized that `purrr::transpose()` could help in a similar way and then I found that `data.table` can transpose lists, as well. The nature of my file is less homogeneous than what I provided in the example, so I will have several match patterns applied to different subsets of the file. I am also trying to import as few packages as possible, as this may end up in its own package. Thank you for idea, though!

Comment: Anytime.
The general idea is to simply make sure the resulting structure is the way you want it to be. I simply picked the first function that came to mind, although I agree that the transpose is more elegant (is it says directly what you want to happen, as opposed to ldply which simply happens to work here)